# Error while importing cordova project to android studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, import, build-tools

I'm getting following error when im trying to import a cordova project.
[image]
But i have build tools 19.1, 20 and higher.

I have latest cordova version 5.1.1 
please refer the below image.
[image]

This is my SDK manager.
[image]

I have checked lot of stackoverflow questions. But no use

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem with my SDK Bundle.I have re-downloaded the whole sdk package and my error gone.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Build Tools are part of the official Android SDK. You can install them by clicking `Tools` -> `Android` -> `SDK Manager`, then find and check the required build tools and click "Install X packages...".

Check if you have that specific version (19.1.0) since there are 5 19.x versions.

Comment: i have installed all build tools given in SDK manager.. Yes i have 19.1.0 and other latest build tools

Comment: Is your project SDK pointing to Android Studios SDK? (right click on your project in AS, properties, SDK Location, you'll see the directory of the currently used SDK, open that directory, then the tools subdir, there will be android.bat, launch it with "android sdk", that will open the SDK manager for that SDK, it should be the same as before unless you have 2 SDKs installed.

Comment: I have only 1 android SDK. I have updated my question with sdk manager screenshot